# google maps showing wrong place

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to draw shapes with given coordinates on google maps. But when I try in this way: http://jsfiddle.net/zzhy/4auzbjd5/3/
it is drawing it but not showing in the correct place.
How can I fix it?

```
var coordinates = r[0].split(":");

var flightPlanCoordinates = new Array();

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

for(i=0;i<coordinates.length;i++)

{  
  var point =new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[i].split(',')[0],coordinates[i].split(',')[1]);

  bounds.extend(point);

  flightPlanCoordinates.push(point);   
}   




var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({

 path: flightPlanCoordinates,

 geodesic: true,

 strokeColor: '#FF0000',

 strokeOpacity: 1.0,

 strokeWeight: 2

 });



flightPath.setMap(map);

map.fitBounds(bounds);
console.log("flightPlanCoordinates:" + flightPlanCoordinates);
console.log("bounds:" + bounds);
```

Comment: Well, what coordinates are you setting it to? The polygon I see in the JSFiddle contains coordinates in Saudi Arabia. Your initial map view is set to somewhere in Turkey, but `map.fitBounds(bounds);` would reassign that.

Comment: @ceejayoz you can check it in this link http://jsfiddle.net/zzhy/4auzbjd5/3/

Comment: The map in that JSfiddle appears correct. What were you expecting? Where do you expect it to show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems the order of the array-items is `longitude,latitude` , but a `google.maps.LatLng` expects `latitude,longitude` .

switch the order of the arguments:

```
var point =new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[i].split(',')[1],coordinates[i].split(',')[0]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4auzbjd5/4/